# Vaadin Table throwing Cannot Convert Object to Number Exception on a manual refresh

Tags: java, vaadin

Okay, so this does probably sound like it's absolutely my mistake, and maybe it is, but please read through the problem first:

I created a table in vaadin which is populated by a list of custom objects. The method I'm using to initialize my table is the same I use to update my table with new values:

```
public void fillTable(List<Order> orders, final User user)
{
    this.removeAllItems();

    for(final Order order : orders)
    {
        final Item currentItem = this.addItem(order);

        currentItem.getItemProperty("musterId").setValue(order.getMusterId());
        currentItem.getItemProperty("name").setValue(order.getName());
        currentItem.getItemProperty("status").setValue(cb);
        currentItem.getItemProperty("user").setValue(order.getUserName());
        currentItem.getItemProperty("lab").setValue(order.getLab().getName());
        currentItem.getItemProperty("supplier").setValue(order.getSupplier() == null ? "" : order.getSupplier().getName());
        currentItem.getItemProperty("amount").setValue(order.getAmount());
        currentItem.getItemProperty("date").setValue(order.getTimeStamp());
        currentItem.getItemProperty("arrivalDate").setValue(order.getArrivalDate());
        currentItem.getItemProperty("comment").setValue(comment);
    }
}
```

I filtered this method a bit as I initialize two UI elements to be shown in the table (cb, which is a ComboBox and comment, which is a TextField).

Now, the problem is that as soon as I refresh the table with the same data (or different, doesn't matter) I will get a "Cannot convert Object to Number"-Exception for the amount-column, which is of type double, for the first object received (amount has the value 1.0). I debugged through the vaadin-sources and all I've found is that at a certain point vaadin is trying to get the value from the property and an empty string is returned, triggering the conversion-exception. The question is: WHY is an empty string returned and why doesn't this error trigger on the initial writing into the table.

I made a workaround where I create a new table as soon as I have to refresh it, taking the old one out of the layout, but that is...well that's a horrible thing to do! Is this a vaadin bug? Am I doing something wrong?

edit: Here's the stack trace:

```
    com.vaadin.ui.Table$CacheUpdateException: Error during Table cache update. Additional causes not shown.
    at com.vaadin.ui.Table.maybeThrowCacheUpdateExceptions(Table.java:1767)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Table.refreshRenderedCells(Table.java:1756)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Table.refreshRowCache(Table.java:2691)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Table.containerItemSetChange(Table.java:4587)
    at com.vaadin.data.util.AbstractContainer.fireItemSetChange(AbstractContainer.java:242)
    at com.vaadin.data.util.AbstractInMemoryContainer.fireItemsAdded(AbstractInMemoryContainer.java:1012)
    at com.vaadin.data.util.AbstractInMemoryContainer.fireItemAdded(AbstractInMemoryContainer.java:994)
    at com.vaadin.data.util.IndexedContainer.fireItemAdded(IndexedContainer.java:627)
    at com.vaadin.data.util.IndexedContainer.addItem(IndexedContainer.java:274)
    at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractSelect.addItem(AbstractSelect.java:905)
    at de.company.ui.components.tables.OrderTable.fillTable(OrderTable.java:85)
    at de.company.ui.pages.OrderPage$1.valueChange(OrderPage.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:508)
    at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:198)
    at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:161)
    at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.fireEvent(AbstractClientConnector.java:1008)
    at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractField.fireValueChange(AbstractField.java:1159)
    at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractField.setValue(AbstractField.java:570)
    at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractSelect.setValue(AbstractSelect.java:732)
    at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractField.setValue(AbstractField.java:468)
    at com.vaadin.ui.ComboBox.changeVariables(ComboBox.java:730)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.changeVariables(ServerRpcHandler.java:603)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocations(ServerRpcHandler.java:422)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:273)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:79)
    at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:41)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1409)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:364)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:769)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1667)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter(WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1650)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:583)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1125)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1059)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:539)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Number
    at java.text.DecimalFormat.format(DecimalFormat.java:505)
    at java.text.Format.format(Format.java:157)
    at com.vaadin.data.util.converter.AbstractStringToNumberConverter.convertToPresentation(AbstractStringToNumberConverter.java:110)
    at com.vaadin.data.util.converter.AbstractStringToNumberConverter.convertToPresentation(AbstractStringToNumberConverter.java:35)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Table.formatPropertyValue(Table.java:4172)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Table.getPropertyValue(Table.java:4114)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Table.parseItemIdToCells(Table.java:2386)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Table.getVisibleCellsNoCache(Table.java:2225)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Table.refreshRenderedCells(Table.java:1745)
    ... 54 more
```

Comment: Can you provide that exception's stack trace?

Comment: Where does the empty string value come from? Are you doing something else than calling fillTable when you refresh the table?

Comment: @Steffen I will try to get the stack trace, just gimme a bit of time
Artur: Nope. It's just that and it crashes on final Item currentItem = this.addItem(order);

Comment: Besides the stacktrace, if you could share a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) will greatly help in this case, since this happens only under certain conditions and there are parts of the code left out.

Comment: @Morfic I know that it would probably be pretty helpful, but that would actually be too much of a hassle. I would wager, though, that every time you use a table with a double value (this.addContainerProperty("amount", Double.class, "", Localization.getString("OrderTable.amount"), null, null);) you'd get that error when you re-use the table? I'm not sure, though.

Comment: Not trying to be patronising here, but since you're asking people to invest time into helping you overcome an issue, it's naturally expected of you to invest the time to provide as much detail as it's required. Furthermore, I had ran a quick test (basic `while/for (i < 10)`) using both a simple test with a default `IndexedContainer` just like you did, as well as using a `BeanItemContainer` and had no issues whatsoever with double values. Without seeing your code we can only assume what you may be doing and overlook something, hence the SSCCE request, for which 15 mins would probably suffice.

Comment: @Morfic I'll see what I can do. Might take a while, but I'll be as quick as possible.

Comment: The quickest way is probably [creating a spring-boot-vaadin project](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Spring+Vaadin/I+-+Getting+Started+with+Vaadin+Spring+and+Spring+Boot), copying the few necessary classes and/or relevant methods from your original project (leaving any sensitive data out), give it a go and see it reproducing, then share it on github or a similar service. All in all, you should be done in 15-30 mins tops. Cheers

Comment: @Morfic The standard demo program with nothing added crashes on me with a "@ConditionalOnMissingBean annotations must specify at least one bean (type, name or annotation)" error...yeah, I'll copy the necessary classes into this topic. Don't need another bug-hunt atm.

Comment: That's weird, I just started a new project, created `MyUi.class` annotated with `@SpringUi` and having `setContent(new VerticalLayout(new Label("It works")));` in its `init()` method, and everything worked perfectly when I launched the auto-generated `MyApplication` class. Did you try to run it in your own tomcat installation perhaps? Either way, whatever suits you best, should be fine.